# MySQL Creating views with variable column names

Tags: mysql, sql

I am logging temperature values using 1-Wire temperature sensors and a Windows application called 'LogTemp'.

This application automatically stores temperature values in a MySQL database.

This is the temperature logging database:

```
mysql> show columns from logtemp; 
+------------------+----------+------+-----+---------------------+-------+ 
| Field | Type | Null | Key | Default | Extra | 
+------------------+----------+------+-----+---------------------+-------+ 
| DATETIME | datetime | NO | PRI | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | | 
| 0400080224D59710 | float | YES | | NULL | | 
| CA00080224DDD010 | float | YES | | NULL | | 
| 5600080224E7FE10 | float | YES | | NULL | | 
| 0500080224D40B10 | float | YES | | NULL | | 
+------------------+----------+------+-----+---------------------+-------+
```

The contents looks like the following:

```
mysql> select * from logtemp limit 10; 
+---------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+ 
| DATETIME | 0400080224D59710 | CA00080224DDD010 | 5600080224E7FE10 | 0500080224D40B10 | 
+---------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+ 
| 2013-11-01 12:58:01 | 25.75 | 24.19 | 24.31 | 24.44 | 
| 2013-11-01 12:59:03 | 25.81 | 24.19 | 24.31 | 24.44 | 
| 2013-11-01 13:00:05 | 25.94 | 24.25 | 24.38 | 24.44 | 
| 2013-11-01 13:01:07 | 25.94 | 24.25 | 24.38 | 24.44 | 
| 2013-11-01 13:02:08 | 25.94 | 24.31 | 24.38 | 24.5 | 
| 2013-11-01 13:03:10 | 26.06 | 24.31 | 24.38 | 24.5 | 
| 2013-11-01 13:04:11 | 26.19 | 24.31 | 24.44 | 24.56 | 
| 2013-11-01 13:05:13 | 26.31 | 24.31 | 24.44 | 24.56 | 
| 2013-11-01 13:06:14 | 26.38 | 24.31 | 24.44 | 24.56 | 
| 2013-11-01 13:07:16 | 26.38 | 24.31 | 24.44 | 24.56 | 
+---------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
```

The column names (0400080224D59710, etc.) are the unique ROM IDs of the temperature sensors. When a new sensor is attached, an additional column in the DB is being created - having the ROM ID of the sensor as column name.

Now, I added another table which looks like this:

```
mysql> show columns from sensoren; 
+--------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+ 
| Field | Type | Null | Key | Default | Extra | 
+--------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+ 
| strSensorHex | varchar(16) | NO | PRI | NULL | | 
| strSensorBeschreibung | varchar(100) | NO | MUL | NULL | | 
| strSensorRRDTabellenName | varchar(25) | NO | | NULL | | 
+--------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

The contents of this table is:

```
mysql> select * from sensoren; 
+------------------+-----------------------+--------------------------+ 
| strSensorHex | strSensorBeschreibung | strSensorRRDTabellenName | 
+------------------+-----------------------+--------------------------+ 
| 0400080224D59710 | Testsensor 1 | TEST1 | 
| CA00080224DDD010 | Testsensor 2 | TEST2 | 
| 5600080224E7FE10 | Testsensor 3 | TEST3 | 
| 0500080224D40B10 | Testsensor 4 | TEST4 | 
+------------------+-----------------------+--------------------------+
```

The `strSensorHex` column contains the unique ROM IDs of the temperature sensors.

Now I would like to create a new view containing the following information:

```
DATETIME, strSensorHex, strSensorBeschreibung, Temperatur value
```

I tried already to google for information about how to realize this but I could not find an answer yet and I am not very familiar with SQL syntax :-(

Comment: This is a bad database design. Variable data should be stored **in** tables, not in column names. Your misdesign is why you can't create a view to display it.

Comment: I agree with Barman's comment, but it doesn't seem to me that it is possible to change the way this program behaves in generating the tables, at least judging from its website.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not possible to change the Database design. It is hard coded in the LogTemp application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution is to use dynamic SQL and a stored procedure instead of a view

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE sensortemp()
BEGIN
  SET @sql = NULL;

  SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(
           'WHEN s.strSensorHex = ''', strSensorHex, ''' THEN `', strSensorHex, '`')
         ORDER BY strSensorHex SEPARATOR ' ')
    INTO @sql
    FROM sensoren;

  SET @sql = CONCAT(
               'SELECT l.datetime, s.strSensorHex, s.strSensorBeschreibung, CASE ', @sql, 'END temperatur
                  FROM logtemp l CROSS JOIN sensoren s
                 ORDER BY l.datetime, s.strSensorBeschreibung'
             );

  PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
  EXECUTE stmt;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END$$
DELiMITER ;
```

Sample usage:

```
CALL sensortemp();
```

Sample output:

```
|            DATETIME |     STRSENSORHEX | STRSENSORBESCHREIBUNG | TEMPERATUR |
|---------------------|------------------|-----------------------|------------|
| 2013-11-01 12:58:01 | 0400080224D59710 |          Testsensor 1 |      25.75 |
| 2013-11-01 12:58:01 | CA00080224DDD010 |          Testsensor 2 |      24.19 |
| 2013-11-01 12:58:01 | 5600080224E7FE10 |          Testsensor 3 |      24.31 |
| 2013-11-01 12:58:01 | 0500080224D40B10 |          Testsensor 4 |      24.44 |
| 2013-11-01 12:59:03 | 0400080224D59710 |          Testsensor 1 |      25.81 |
| 2013-11-01 12:59:03 | CA00080224DDD010 |          Testsensor 2 |      24.19 |
| 2013-11-01 12:59:03 | 5600080224E7FE10 |          Testsensor 3 |      24.31 |
| 2013-11-01 12:59:03 | 0500080224D40B10 |          Testsensor 4 |      24.44 |
| 2013-11-01 13:00:05 | 0400080224D59710 |          Testsensor 1 |      25.94 |
| 2013-11-01 13:00:05 | CA00080224DDD010 |          Testsensor 2 |      24.25 |
| 2013-11-01 13:00:05 | 5600080224E7FE10 |          Testsensor 3 |      24.38 |
| 2013-11-01 13:00:05 | 0500080224D40B10 |          Testsensor 4 |      24.44 |
...
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/48ee6f)** demo

---

**UPDATE:** Based on your comments: you can use above mentioned code to help you build a definition for a view (basically what Gordon Linoff suggested in his answer). The definition of your view might look like

```
CREATE VIEW vw_sensorentemp AS
  SELECT l.datetime, s.strSensorHex, s.strSensorBeschreibung, 
         CASE s.strSensorHex 
           WHEN '0400080224D59710' THEN `0400080224D59710` 
           WHEN '0500080224D40B10' THEN `0500080224D40B10` 
           WHEN '5600080224E7FE10' THEN `5600080224E7FE10` 
           WHEN 'CA00080224DDD010' THEN `CA00080224DDD010` 
         END temperatur 
  FROM logtemp l CROSS JOIN sensoren s;
```

Now you can use it to sort results differently

```
SELECT * 
  FROM vw_sensorentemp
 ORDER BY strSensorBeschreibung DESC;
```

or join with other tables.

**Note:** You'll have to update the view's definition each time you add new or delete some sensors.

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a283b2/1)** working demo for that scenario.

Comment: The Stored Procedure works perfect (just the decimal places are not limited to two ->      | 2013-11-01 12:58:01 | CA00080224DDD010 | Testsensor 2          | 24.190000534057617 |).  But I would prefer a view if possible to be able to join the data with other data or to sort it different. Unfortunately Gordon's Suggestion does not work.

Comment: @Piet Decimal places are limited in my example because I used `decimal(19, 2)` data type instead of `float`. It was just for the example. It will perfectly work with float. If possible use cases for joining and changing the sort order are limited (which in real life is usually true) you can extend the procedure to handle these cases with dynamic SQL by passing appropriate parameters  and constructing the proper query string on the fly

Comment: @Piet See updated answer for a working example with the view approach

Comment: if I Change the datatype to decimal(19,2) I get the 2 Digits as expected :-)  Unfortunately I do not have deep SQL know how to be able to make the changes to the procedure with dynamic SQL on the fly.  But thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @Piet You're quite welcome :). If you have to use `float` data type but you need to present only 2 digits after the decimal point you can use `ROUND()` function. Here is an [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f67d01/1) example for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit long for a comment, but it includes two ideas for solving this problem.

Although I agree with BarMar's comment, I recognize that the in the real world, things may not be so easily defined.

Defining the query for a known list sensors isn't a problem.  Something like:

```
select DATETIME, s.strSensorHex, s.strSensorBeschreibung,
       (case when s.strSensorHex = '0400080224D59710' then lt.`0400080224D59710`
             . . .
        end) as Temperatur
from logtemp lt cross join
     sensoren s;
```

The list of sensors is hardcoded in a series of `when` statements in the `case` statement.  And, happily, you can put this in a view, just by putting a `create view <blah> as` statement before it.

The problem is adding a new sensor.  The view is not dynamic and cannot be made dynamic to understand new sensor values . . . but, you can use a prepared statement to create the SQL with the new `case` clause to incorporate the logic.

My first suggestion is that you create a stored procedure to handle the process of adding a new sensor.  Part of this stored procedure is to re-create the view using a prepared statement to re-define the view.

An alternative, which might work, would be to take an audit-table approach.  Add an `insert` trigger to the `logtemp` table.  This insert trigger would insert rows into another table, with just one row per sensor.  You might also need an `update` trigger as well.

Comment: Unfortunately, this proposal does not work.  mysql> select DATETIME, s.strSensorHex, s.strSensorBeschreibung
    -> (case when s.strSensorHex = '0400080224D59710' then lt.`0400080224D59710`
    -> end) as Temperatur
    -> from logtemp lt cross join sensoren s;
ERROR 1305 (42000): FUNCTION s.strSensorBeschreibung does not exist